# Powershell notify when certificate almost expires

Tags: powershell, certificate

In Powershell I want to notify specific users when a certificate in a domain controller is gonna expire 24hour before hand. I already found a code then displays the start and expiry date and also the days remaining. But how can i get notified (through email) when the certificate expires.

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My `
   | Select @{N='StartDate';E={$_.NotBefore}},
   @{N='EndDate';E={$_.NotAfter}},
   @{N='DaysRemaining';E={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}}
```

Comment: Pass that code to `Send-MailMessage`? Have you tried anything? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Note that Microsoft [no longer recommends the use of Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1#description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest adding some more properties to the objects you select for better recognition later and add a `Where-Object{}` clause to it, to filter for certificates that have 1 day or less left before expiring:

```
$certs = Get-ChildItem -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My' |
   Select-Object Thumbprint, Issuer,
                 @{N='StartDate';E={$_.NotBefore}},
                 @{N='EndDate';E={$_.NotAfter}},
                 @{N='DaysRemaining';E={($_.NotAfter - (Get-Date).Date).Days}}  |
   Where-Object { $_.DaysRemaining -le 1 }

if ($certs) {
    # send an email to yourself
    $mailSplat = @{
        To         = 'me@mycompany.com'
        From       = 'me@mycompany.com'
        SmtpServer = 'MySmtpServer'
        Subject    = 'Expiring certificates'
        Body       = $certs | Format-List | Out-String
        # other params can go here
    }
    # send the email
    Send-MailMessage @mailSplat
}
```

<sup>`(Get-Date).Date` takes today's date as of midnight, not at the current time of day you run the script</sup>

Comment: Hey there, sorry I was a bit busy. Your code looks good but when I try to send the mail message i get the error: Unable to connect to the remote server. I tried it with gmail account and also added several ports like 25 and 587 but doesn't seem to be working..

Comment: @Ruan2106 That I'm afraid has nothing to do with the question you have asked. There are **LOTS** of questions about sending email using gmail and at least that many answers too you can find all over the internet. Bottom line is you have to change some settings in your gmail account first to make it 'Less secure' to make that work.